# How do you find the Jitterbit Harmony Http HostedEndpoint SERVERNAME & PORT combination?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage, http, jitterbit

I'm sending an outbound message from SFDC to Jitterbit.  The Jitterbit "NO-Cumentation" 
http://support.jitterbit.com/documentation/How-to-Create-a-Hosted-HTTP-Endpoint

states:
 ... "the end-point will be triggered when the URL 'http://[server name]:[server port]/'...

The listener gotta be within the jitterbit domain;  but I can't find a single reference to what the url/port is.

Will appreciate if anyone can point me  to wherever I can find a link to this.

Thanks

Comment: @Sahal and Solees have contributed that the port is 46908.  No idea how the servername is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The server is YOUR local agent server, with the port number being the standard port mentioned, unless you altered your config to a different port, or are doing some port forwarding from the public Internet to your agent server box.

Comment: Hi @JimRae,  Thanks for the contribution !  Now, this would mean I need to  keep an online, on-premise system running the jitterbit agent, at any time the outbound message would be sent... Which could be anytime.   The port must also be opened at the firewall/published out to the internet...  Is this correct?  I find the requirement... inefficient.  Have you seen a more  cost effective alternative? I'm thinking an Azure VM running the agent.   Your take?

Comment: ugh, can't upvote your answer! I need 15 rep...

Comment: You are correct @RafaelSuarez.  I suppose it depends on all of the integration requirements you have. If you are connecting to any on premise databases, you would need the local agent support anyway (that is my use case).  Jitterbit claims they are going to support using the cloud agent in an upcoming release, but didn't provide any specifics.  Regarding other more effective solutions, really depends on your use case.  I am running the agent (which has a fairly small footprint) on the same box as we use for our website and ftp server.